# Need to ask this question. Where do I ask this?

Tags: support

"
I have a HP Touchpad with Windows 10 Home Edition. I forgot the admin password. Now I cannot do system restore. After I reboot and hit F2, it takes me to a system information page. I do not see an option to do system restore.
"
It was considered off-topic. Not sure why?

Comment: It's not off topic, but the question is answered elsewhere (duplicate).

Comment: You asked your [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1448484/trying-to-restore-my-hp-tablet-to-factory-codition) and it was marked as a duplicate.